# Html.ActionLink not appending server url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC application where I need to show hyperlink. I am using

```
@Html.ActionLink
```

problem is that , its rendering localhost url on server.

E.g. my code is as below

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink(@Model.ID.ToString(), "Edit","AIQs", new { id = @Model.ID}, new { @class = "forgot-txt" })</td>
```

but hyperlink URL , its generating is :

```
https://localhost/aim/AIQs/Edit?id=101
```

It should be server url instead of localhost

Comment: Use an absolute URL starting with i.e. http://.

Comment: Why not just using `a` anchor tag with absolute path? See [ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx) definition, it doesn't mention domain name (means it's relative to application definition in IIS).

Answer (score 0):

You can force your host name into `actionlink` according to your mind:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go to contact page", "Edit", "AIQs", "yourprotocol", "yourhostname", "anchorname", routeValues, attributes)
```

Also you can see this useful article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492938(v=vs.118).aspx